# Modern System Architecture?

Tags: c, operating-system, mutex, semaphore

What could happen if we used Peterson's solution to the critical section problem on a modern computer? It is my understanding that systems with multiple CPUs can run into difficulty because of the ordering of memory reads and writes with respect to other reads and writes in memory, but is this the problem with most modern systems? Are there any advantages to using semaphores VS mutex locks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hey interesting question! So basically in order to understand what you're asking you have to ensure that you know what it is you're asking. The **critical section** is just the part of a program that should not be concurrently executed by any more than one of that program's processes or threads at a time. Multiple concurrent accesses are not allowed, so all that means is that only one process is interacting with the system at a time. Typically this "*critical section*" accesses a resource like a data structure, or network connection.

**Mutual Exclusion** or **mutex** just describes the requirement that only one concurrent process is in the critical section at a time, so concurrent access to shared data must ensure this "mutual exclusion".

So this introduces the problem! How do we assure that processes run completely independently of other processes, in other words, how do we ensure "*atomic access*" to the various critical sections by the threads?

There are a few solutions to the "critical-section problem" but the one you mention is *Peterson's solution* so we will discuss that.

Peterson's algorithm is designed for mutual exclusion and allows two tasks to share a single-use resource. They use shared memory for communicating.

In the algorithm, two tasks will compete for the critical section; you'll have to look into mutex, bound waiting and other properties a bit more for a full understanding, but the just of it is that in peterson's method, a process waits 1 turn and 1 turn only to get entrance into the critical section, if it gives priority to the other task or process, then that process will run to completion and hereby allowing the other process to enter the critical section.

That is the original solution proposed.

However this has no guarantee of working on today's multiprocessing modern architectures and it only works for two concurrent tasks. It is kind of messy on modern computers when it comes to reading and writing because it has an out-of-order type of execution, so sometimes sequential operations happen in an incorrect order and thus there are limitations. I suggest you also take a look at *locks*. Hope that helps :)

Can anyone else think of anything to add that I might have missed?

Comment: That is super helpful!! Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

> It is my understanding that systems with multiple CPUs can run into difficulty because of the ordering of memory reads and writes with respect to other reads and writes in memory, but is this the problem with most modern systems?

No. Any modern systems with "less strict" memory ordering will have ways to make the memory ordering more strict where it matters (e.g. fences).

> Are there any advantages to using semaphores VS mutex locks?

Mutexes are typically simpler and faster (in the same way that a boolean is simpler than a counter); but ignoring overhead a mutex is equivalent to a semaphore with "resource count = 1".

> What could happen if we used Peterson's solution to the critical section problem on a modern computer?

The big problem here is that most modern operating systems support some kind of multi-tasking (e.g. multiple processes, where each process can have multiple threads), there's usually 100 other processes (just for the OS alone), and modern hardware has power management (where you try to avoid power consumption by putting CPUs to sleep when they can't do useful work). This means that (unbounded) spinning/busy waiting is a horrible idea (e.g. you can have N CPUs being wasted spinning/trying to acquire a lock while the task that currently holds the lock isn't running on any CPU because the scheduler decided that 1234 other tasks should get 10 ms of CPU time each).

Instead; to avoid (excessive) spinning you want to ask the scheduler to block your task until/unless the lock actually can be acquired; and (especially for heavily contended locks) you probably want "fairness" (to avoid the risk of timing problems that lead to some tasks being repeatedly lucky while other tasks starve and make no progress).

This ends up being "no spinning", or "brief spinning" (to avoid scheduler overhead in cases where the task holding the lock actually can/does release it quickly); followed by the task being put on a FIFO queue and the scheduler giving the CPU to a different task or putting the CPU to sleep; where if the lock is released the scheduler wakes up the first task on the FIFO queue. Of course it's never that simple (e.g. for performance you want to do as much as you can in user-space; and you need special care and cooperating between user-space and kernel to avoid race conditions - the lock being released before a task is put on the wait queue).

Fortunately modern systems also provide simpler ways to implement locks (e.g. "atomic compare and swap"), so there's no need to resort to Peterson's algorithm (even if its just for insertion/removal of tasks from the real lock's FIFO queue).

Comment: Thank you for the clarity! I'm better able to wrap my  head around the concepts now!